# Is a worm-like-chain purely entropic?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, biophysics, polymers

I consider a worm-like chain with the Hamiltonian given by:
\begin{equation}
H(L)=\frac{\kappa}{2}\int_{0}^{L}ds\left(\frac{\partial\vec{t}}{\partial s}\right)^2
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$ is the bending module $L$ the length of the polymer and $\vec{t}$ unit vector tangent to the polymer.

I try to calculate its partition function. After some lengthy calculations (that I could add if it is necessary) I got that it is equal to 1.

That result is more than unintuitive for me. It would imply that its free energy is always equal to 0 and therefore its behaviour is purely entropic. But here we indeed have non-zero bending energy so I would expect highly curved polymer to be less probable as it requires some energy to bend it. Therefore I would expect free energy entropy competition determining its behaviour.

Is that result correct? If yes then why and why my intuition is wrong?

Comment: Have you read Marantan and Mahadevan, "[Mechanics and statistics of the worm-like chain](https://softmath.seas.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/2018-01.pdf)," *Am J Phys* (2018)?

Comment: no, thank you for the resource! Could you maybe refer to a specific part of the article?

Comment: Perhaps the section on calculating the partition function.